# Display name in react-native (Ios, Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

My application name is (Feruz Academy) but on the phone it is displayed like this (FeruzAcad...) why is this?

I searched but didn’t find a solution, looked in different libraries, tried nothing, nothing changed. Maybe I didn't find the answer, please help)

Answer (score 1):

In your app_name (where you specify the app name string), write this:

```
Feruz&#x2007;Academy
```

**UPDATE:**

If the app name is too long, some devices will not support the app name length.

Your best bet then, is to come up with a shorter name. Maybe an acronym, so it works on all devices

Comment: in info.plist ?

Comment: wherever you specify your app name, yes

Comment: I did as you said right now the name displays (Feruz Acad...) and it should display (Feruz Academy)

Comment: Ah that's because the name of your app is too long. The device is truncating the name if it exceeds the app length

Comment: It sounds like you might need to come up with a shorter name. Maybe an acronym? So it works on all devices (especially ones that don't meet the minimum string length requirements)

Comment: but I have an application whose name is also so long but its name is fully displayed)

Comment: I have a program called (Ipak Yo'li Mobile) and it is displayed completely

Comment: On your info.plist can you specify the name: 

Feruz&#x2007;Academy

And on android on your manifest.xml can you go to the Application tag, and write: 
android:label="Feruz&#x2007;Academy"

Comment: yes it works inside two words a space appears but the name is not displayed completely. I have one phone, here is my program which you said that the name is long, but there is another program with a longer name than mine, so I’m wondering why that is?

Comment: So are you testing the apps on the same device? So the other app with the long name is not being truncated, while yours is?

Comment: Yes, I have a program, its name is longer than my program, but its name is displayed in full. I downloaded the program for myself via TestFlight and checked, but my name is not displayed full